# Latex nomenclature - unwanted space between some letters?

Tags: spacing, italic, nomenclature, letterspacing

I have a problem with the \nomenclature in Latex. In two cases (strangely when I use the word 'Effect'), the spacing between the first three letters in the description appears to be larger (please see the attached screenshot. I needed to censor some parts).

The code for the creation of the nomenclature is as follows:

```
\nomenclature[z]{$RPPE$}{$Relative~(...)~Effect$}
```

The '~' in between words in the description is needed because otherwise, there appears to be no space between the words (the (...) is censoring, again). I use the same code for all items that appear in the nomenclature, only the word 'Effect' seems to cause a problem.

What could cause this issue?
[image]

Comment: That is the expected result of setting text in math mode: You get very odd looking spacing. Remove the dollar signs around `Relative~(...)~Effect` for a better result.

Comment: Oh, and if you're using dollar signs for italics, don't. Use `\textit{Relative~(...)~Effect}` instead.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use dollar signs for italics. We have the `\textit{…}` construct for that purpose.

Longer explanation: The spacing in math mode is designed for use in formulas. In math mode, “Effect” would be the product of variables *E*, *f*, *f*, *e*, *c* and *t*. Especially the letter *f* in math mode has quite generous surrounding space, since otherwise, the letter tends to get mashed into the surrounding material.

As you have found, the resulting spacing looks really strange if read as text.

Sometimes, you need text in math mode. There are special constructs for that (`\text` among them).